# Unable to add the index in kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have published jira* index pattern and its available in Kibana as like below

[image]
Clicked "Next Step" button --> clicked create index button and observed below error message:

[image]

And the jira index having the below sample data which is not having the timestamp. I don't have control to append any data into this response.json file. All I want is that wanna show this in chart y row count 4 and x row all these JIRA ID.

**Sample data for jira index:**

```
  {
    "JIRA-1":"KINDLEAMZ-67578",

    "JIRA-2":"KINDLEAMZ-68661",

    "JIRA-3":"KINDLEAMZ-68167"

    }
```

Can someone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> elasticsearch's index is made read-only and never set back when disk
>   watermark reached high

**To fix unlock issue for all indexes manually:**

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://[ES_HOST]:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

`ES_HOST` is where you're running your elasticsearch

**Source**: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/13685#issuecomment-345859559

If it doesn't help check it out : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/solved-forbidden-to-create-index-pattern-in-kibana-7-2/190947/9

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan glad it helped you somehow, best of luck :)